# How Do I Know When I am in Private Mode?

Tags: safari, mojave

Using Chrome, there is a little icon indicating that I am in Private mode. Maybe I am missing something, but how do I know in Safari?  I don't see any indication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Mojave, the address bar has different shades of gray/black depending on whether you're in private mode or not.

[image]

In light mode it's light gray for not private, and a dark gray for private mode.

In dark mode it's black for private, a fairly medium gray for not private.

Comment: The same color scheme is used in iOS 13+ dark mode.

Comment: The difference is very subtle in dark mode, barely noticeable.

Comment: @Siddhartha, You definition of "subtle" is not the same as mine as one can plainly see the difference between normal and private in each mode, especially the dark mode a private tab/window address bar is black vs medium gray. In either mode there is considerable contrast in color of the address bar and nothing subtle about it.

Comment: @user3439894 there's contrast for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if someone thought that a dark address bar came with the dark mode, and didn't remember what shade of gray its supposed to be. (Gray vs almost white) on white is far more obvious than (gray vs dark gray) on dark gray.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on any link, see if it says `Open Link in New Tab` or `Open Link in New Private Tab`. The latter means you're in private mode.

Comment: To me, the question is more about how on tell a given Safari window or tab is in private mode just by looking at it, **not** to have to click a link; however, for those that feel the contrast is too subtle to tell at a glance, your answer gives them a way to confirm. +1